# PHP make directory folder

Tags: php

I have already define my selected folder name to create in my mkdir method. But error saying that "mkdir(): No such file or directory". The directory is correct if I removed away the "/"."Folder"."/".

```
Updated Working code:
$Name = "John";
if(!is_dir("document/".$Name))
{
$dir = "documents/".$Name."/";
    mkdir($dir,0777,true);
    $dir2 = $dir."Folder/";
    mkdir($dir2);
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],$dir2."/".$_FILES["file"]["name"]);

}
```

Thanks to xdazz!

Comment: Why "/"."Folder"." ?
Shouldn't that be "/Folder/" ?

Comment: want to create a inner folder to store that particular document. Even i change it to "/Folder/". It still gives me the same error

Comment: Are you sure that `'documents/'.$Name;` exists? `mkdir` won't create missing folders in path.

Comment: Yes, it exists. I can successfully created 'documents/'.$Name; But not "documents/".$Name."/"."Folder"."/";

Comment: @user976050 The way you use `mkdir` won't create missing folders. For example, `mkdir('document/'.$name);` will create folder with the name that will be value of $name. but `mkdir('document/'.$name.'/folder');` won't create first folder $name and then "folder" inside if the folder named by $name is missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `mkdir($dir,0777, true);`, `"document/".$Name` is not a dir yet, so you need to make dir recursive .

Comment: @user976050 The third parameter of `mkdir` let you make dir recursive, did you try it?

Comment: Anyway is there any other way I can automatic create the folder behind the "document/".$Name."/". Means create document/Name/Folder, document/Name/Folder1..